# How to appear two HTML input elements in single line (row)

Tags: html, css

This code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" tabindex="1"></div>
```

Though with repeated efforts starting from adding `tabindex`, `nbsp` to `css` cannot have these two inputs appear on single line.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.category {
      vertical-align:top;
   }
 </style>
```

**UPDATE**

I think there is a plugin css which is over-ridding this behaviour. I have applied all what you guys said nothing works here is the css. I'm using plugin **mcdropdown**. Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xW3tt/1/) at start is just the copy of `style` followed with is is the css copy paste of mcdropdown.css file.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: how does the css for the surounding block look?

Comment: `input:text` are inline elements. They will appear in a single line by default.

Comment: `input.category` will select all the `inputs` that have **class** `category` - use`<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="" class="category>`

Comment: @Vucko thanks for noticing the error I have added class but still doesn't works.

Comment: That is the CSS i need to see the surounding DOM also your jsfiddle isn't correct.

Comment: @for the css without HTML code pls download here.http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm The DOM declaration is used as <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="" />

Comment: @PhilipG i have included div in the sorrounded DOM. Is that enough?

Comment: over-ride plugin CSS using `!important`

Comment: @PrasanthKC how can i do that? I want to use css for rendering out drop-down menu? I just twant to over-ride the part where it doesn't allow me to put to inputs on single row?

Comment: @user3066819 First you find out which CSS block your inputs from being inline, You can check it by inspecting elements through **developer tools**. then over-ride those properties using `!important`

Comment: @user3066819 but in your updated fiddle both inputs seems to be in single line. just like you wanted.. rite??

Comment: @PrasanthKC this is right coz the plugin css are not included in the demo. In the code the plugin doesn't let these input to show inline

Comment: @user3066819 I have added an answer, pls check, but keep in mind that its a wild guessed answer. Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: @PrasanthKC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445899/cannot-hack-pass-css-plugin-to-make-two-input-elements-appears-in-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add class="category" for input fields and css:

```
.category {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#category_1 {
  margin-left: 20px; /* or space you want..*/
}
```

and remove those spaces (`&nbsp;`) not really good way to code :)

Benefit of changing element display to block is that you can set **vertical** margins and paddings to it when needed.

Example usage with labels could be:

html:

```
<div class="col1">
  <label for="field1">Field1 title</label>
  <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" /> 
</div>

<div class="col2">
  <label for="field2">Field2 title</label>
  <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" /> 
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get them to display on a single line use the css display attribute to change their display to inline here is how I do it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #category, #category_1{
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="">
    <input type="text" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" tabindex="1">

</body>
```

That should solve your problem and it's really simple to! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

They are both inline elements and should appear on the same line by default. Close your input tags appropriately `(<input... />)` and remove the closing `</div>` tag:

change

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" tabindex="1"></div>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" tabindex="1" />
```

Comment: I have moved the question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445899/cannot-hack-pass-css-plugin-to-make-two-input-elements-appears-in-line

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, By default your elements aligned and dispalyed in single line. If you want to apply any css styling or css properties then you may use as like in below. Added class in input elements `class="category"`

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.category {
       float:left;
          width:100px;
   }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div style='width:500px;'>
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="" class="category">
    <input type="text" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" class="category" tabindex="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by removing float, and add `display:inline-block`. 
Here: http://jsfiddle.net/xW3tt/2/

Comment: from the inline style. Also you can use "!important" to be sure it wont be overwritten from other places

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a wild guess operation, Try

Try applying below CSS to over-ride:

```
input.category {
      float:left !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding:0 !important;
      clear:none !important;
   }
```

and apply `.category` class to both your `input` (*SEE FIDDLE)

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QjdT9/)

Comment: Please can you reply me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445899/cannot-hack-pass-css-plugin-to-make-two-input-elements-appears-in-line I have re-posted with more clarity now.