# Cannot hack pass css plugin to make two input elements appears in-line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a plugin for **drop down menu**. The link for plugin is [here.](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm). I want to add this code, into already made html code, but first I wanted to tested. So, far it all works fine until I try to make two copies of widget and make them appear side by side. The default is for input element to appear in-line but the plugin css is pushing it down turning into a single column (stacked) I don't want this. Here is HTML code.

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mcdropdown.js"></script>

<!---// load the mcDropdown CSS stylesheet //--->
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mcdropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>



<body>
<ul id="categorymenu" class="mcdropdown_menu">
  <li rel="1">
    Arts &amp; Humanities
    <ul>
      <li rel="2">
        Photography
        <ul>
          <li rel="3">
            3D
          </li>
          <li rel="4">
            Digital
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li rel="5">
        History
      </li>
      <li rel="6">
        Literature
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li rel="7">
    Business &amp; Economy
  </li>
  <li rel="8">
    Computers &amp; Internet
  </li>
  <li rel="9">
    Education
  </li>
  <li rel="11">
    Entertainment
    <ul>
      <li rel="12">
        Movies
      </li>
      <li rel="13">
        TV Shows
      </li>
      <li rel="14">
        Music
      </li>
      <li rel="15">
        Humor
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li rel="10">
    Health
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="test"> <input type="text" class="category" name="category" id="category" value="" />
<input type="text" class="category" name="category" id="category_1" value="" /></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#category").mcDropdown("#categorymenu");
    $("#category_1").mcDropdown("#categorymenu");

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS PLUGIN**

```
/* 
    styles for the psuedo-select box 
*/
div.mcdropdown {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #8e9daa;
    padding: 1px;
    display: -moz-inline-block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 408px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
}

/* style either the input or div where the plug-in is attached to */
div.mcdropdown input, 
div.mcdropdown div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 98%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 0 3px;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.mcdropdown a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background: transparent url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_select_button_sprite.gif) no-repeat top left;
    display: -moz-inline-block;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0pt;
    z-index: 2;
    outline: 0;
}

div.mcdropdown a:hover, div.mcdropdown a:focus {
    background-position: 0% -16px;
}

div.mcdropdown a:active {
    background-position: 0% -32px;
    outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled {
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore; 
    -moz-user-input: disabled; 
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled input {
    cursor: default;
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled a:hover, div.mcdropdownDisabled a:focus {
    background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: default;
}

/* 
    styles for the dropdown menu 
*/
ul.mcdropdown_menu {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    /* float so we can calculate the size of the columns */
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 10000;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore; 
    -moz-user-input: disabled; 
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    display: none;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* float so we can calculate the size of the columns */
/*
    float: left;
*/
}

/* -- Sub-Menus -- */
ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 150px;
    _width: 150px; /* ie6 min-width hack */
}


/* color schema */
ul.mcdropdown_menu {
/*
    height: 19px;
*/
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    /* define font here for IE6 */
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li {
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 6px;
    /* this is needed to ensure that all browsers have the same line-height--fixes issues in Chrome (Mac) and IE10 */
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* we don't use "ul.mcdropdown_menu > li" here so that IE6 knows how to style the root level */
ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_root {
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 6px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/* this is for IE6 only */
ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_hover {
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #999 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover + li:not(.mc_firstrow) {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_parent {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    background: url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_normal.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li:hover.mc_parent {
    background: #999 url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_hover.gif) no-repeat 100% 50% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    /* add a slight border for better visualization of deep menus */
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /* IE 6/7 will bleed through the background color if we don't set the visibility to hidden */
    visibility: hidden;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #666;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_firstrow {
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    color: #666;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_endcol:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li:hover + li:not(.mc_firstrow) {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}

/*
 * drop down shadows
 */
div.mcdropdown_shadow {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    /* for IE6, we use just a square transparent image */
    background: #000;
    filter :alpha(opacity=33);
}

/* ie6 ignores this selector */
html>body div.mcdropdown_shadow {
    /* let's use a transparent PNG */
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    background: transparent url(../images/mcdropdown/shadow.png) right bottom no-repeat !important;
    /* remove the filter for IE7 */
    filter: none;
}

/* 
 * styles for the dropdown menu 
 */
/* autocomplete styles */
ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete {
    display: block;
  position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 210px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  clear: both;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    z-index: 10000;

    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 392px;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete ul li {
    margin: 0px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li {
  display: block;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 26px 2px 6px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_parent {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    background: url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_normal.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #999 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_hover_parent {
    background: #999 url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_hover.gif) no-repeat 100% 50% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Things I have tried that Failed

```
.category {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#category_1 {
  margin-left: 20px; /* or space you want..*/
}

    <style>
        #category, #category_1{
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
```

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to use two instances of this dropdown plugin in same page.. rite??

Comment: if i am correct you are looking to implement two dropdowns positioned side by side.. am i rite??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
div.test > div { 
    float: left; 
    width: 408px; 
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: it worked:))) you are genius how did you find what the problem was? can you please educate me little for future ref..

Comment: :) glad it worked. The plugin you're using dynamically wraps your <input>'s in <div>'s. Divs are block elements, that is, they take up all horizontal space, 100%. That's why your inputs (or dropdown lists at that stage) appeared on separate horizontal lines. To see what the resulting document tree (the DOM) looks like, you can use F12 developer tools in IE or Chrome, or Firebug in FF.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, using ff i can see that plugin css wraps it down with div named mcdropdown, so your code kinda over-ride this? Because > sign symbolizes the function...

Comment: Not overrides but applies (there's nothing to override in this particular case). The > selector targets direct children of your <div class="test"...> element.

Comment: So not over-ride but the precedence is taken over from .css file when desc in html style body right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you have inline style it overrides any rules coming from a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the plugin page:**

> NOTE: The initial element that you apply the plug-in to is destroyed
>   and replaced with a new input element with the same id attribute.
>   While the mcDropdown() method does not destroy the jQuery chain, it
>   does effectively return a "dirty" reference (since the original
>   element no longer exists.) Because of this, you'll want to make sure
>   that the mcDropdown() method is the last call in your chain. Also, if
>   you plan on caching a reference to the element, you will need to
>   create the cached instance after you initiated the widget.

Honestly I'm not even sure if that's related.

But your code (albeit not functioning as advertised) is lining up the way you want when I look at it.
[Here's a fiddle for you to see what I see.](http://jsfiddle.net/q6mKK/)

Keep in mind of course that I'm not sure why it's not functioning properly.  I put it on my desktop and replicated the whole example as-is and still nothing.  But the input boxes are nice and neat :)

I did notice you left off the `jquery.bgiframe.js` file but I don't think that's necessary.